# OCR Library written for a free server

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, ocr, openshift

I'm looking for an OCR library that is capable of running off of a free server (eg. free Python/PHP webhost, Google App Engine, OpenShift). Tesseract seems to provide accurate enough results for my use (OCRing one short word). However, it is written in C and that is not going to be able to run off of a free server or at least the ones that I have come across so far. I can't provide my own server because I don't have the resources for one (only a laptop that isn't always on). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you need a free-to-use Python/PHP OCR class? I don't get the rest of it. Just ask what you need, *free Python and/or PHP OCR script*.

Comment: Yah but one that can run off of a service such as Google App Engine, Kodingen, or OpenShift. I don't want one that is just a binding to a unsupported language (such as C/C++).

Comment: I don't know a thing about servers, but have you looked at [this](https://github.com/rosarior/pytesser)?

Comment: Appengines conversion service does support OCR https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview

Comment: @BrtH
I did, its a wrapper around the C executable which can't be run off of any of the servers I'm working with.

Comment: @TimHoffman
Thanks that's probably what I'm gonna use. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When I posted this answer googles conversion service did appear to be a good solution, but on Aug 15, 2012 google announced the conversion service will be dropped in November 2012.**

Appengines conversion service does support OCR developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview

You don't even need to run it on the server if you are just mucking around as long as you instance has remote api enabled.  Here is an example of calling the OCR service via the remote_api and not have to deploy code on the remote server.

```
App Engine interactive console for qtrack-dev
>>> from google.appengine.api import conversion
>>> asset = conversion.Asset("text/html", "<b>some data</b>", "test.html")
>>> conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "image/png")
>>> result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
Username:XXXXXg@gmail.com
Password:
>>> result.assets
[<google.appengine.api.conversion.conversion.Asset object at 0x9e4642c>]

>>> open('/tmp/x.png','w').write(result.assets[0].data)
>>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately google announced in the last couple of days (Aug 15, 2012) they are going to discontinue the conversion api in the near future ;-(  So my answer has just become a bit useless.